# MKMapView Overlays are not sharply drawn after zoom action

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am currently working on a map feature (most of the code was developed by someone else for this feature).

We are adding mkoverlays to the map by setting up an array of mkpolygon objects. These objects receive their polygons coordinates by a received jSon from backend. As far as I have checked the code, we are not overriding the draw methods. The objects are only initialised with their polygons and added to the mapView.

We are adding lines and polygons to the map by this approach and now there are two behaviours which are not nice:

1) if polygon overlays are touched, their color should be changed -> but its very very slow
2) if the map is zoomed in/out, the lines are very pixeled and not sharp - looks very crappy

My question is, is the whole approach wrong for this use case?

Comment: Having both of these issues as well. As far as I can tell, the entire map repaints if an overlay renderer gets set as needs display. And the renderer gets asked to draw outside of its bounds. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Our map-based app also has very slow overlay rendering and (intermittent) excessive blurring around the edges.

The good news is that I found a workaround for what looks like a bug to me that resulted in a 300% performance improvement. I noticed that the renderer was being asked repeatedly to draw outside of the overlay's bounds. So I just added a bounds check to the draw method of my `MKPolygonRenderer` subclass like this:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if (!MKMapRectIntersectsRect([self.overlay boundingMapRect], mapRect)) {
        return;
    }
    [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
}
```

With this change, we improved from less than 1 redraw per second to 2 or 3 redraws per second.

Comment: What does self.overlay contains, is it just 1 overlay? What id we have an array of overlays? Also, who calls drawMapRect? Thanks!

Comment: @VanDuTran These are APIs on Apple's `MKOverlayRenderer` class, so I'm not sure I understand the question. The `overlay` property is of type `id<MKOverlay>`. So, no it is not an array. And `drawMapRect` gets called by internal Apple code. You can take a look at [the sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2183704/Map%20Overlay%20Pared%20Down.zip) I sent Apple if it helps

Comment: What I actually meant was, when does the API refresh the overlays? When does "rendererForOverlays" is called? I do not get the relationship between the drawMapRect and the rendererForOverlay